# Creating Graph for NDVI Raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, graph

I want to represent the NDVI value creating Graph in ArcMap for the NDVI map as shown:

[image]

However, when I try to create a map for the NDVI values in ArcMap, the layer is not shown:

[image]

How can this issue be fixed and the graph be created for this NDVI raster map?

Comment: That is really weird, you're following the instructions correctly https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/graphs/creating-histogram-graphs.htm but you're stalled at the first stage. Perhaps it's not liking your raster because it doesn't have statistics calculated, try running *'Calculate Statistics'* https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm

Comment: @MichaelStimson I tried using it but using calculate statistics provide information about data in document file type; but I want the statistics value of raster be represented directly on the ArcMap.

Comment: I just tried it using the instructions, even with the statistics calculated there was no raster in the layers to check. I think your only option is to perform *'Raster to Point'*  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-point.htm and use that to create your histogram graph; to embed the graph in your layout open Graph Manager, right click on your graph and select *'Add to Layout'* to make the graph printable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your raster is not an integer raster, it's probably a float 32. The graph tool will not work with such rasters in that format.

You can employ a trick and multiply the raster by 1 million to move the decimal point 6 places to the right. Pass that output through the [int()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/int.htm) tool to ensure it becomes an integer raster. You will now be able to create your histogram. Just be aware that you would need to divide the values by 1 million to return them to the true NDVI value.

This approach works well if you want to just look at the data. If you want to create a quality figure for a report then you might need to do what @MichaelStimson suggests as you will have more control over the final design of the graph.